# ICEFaces & GWT Integration: ICEPush

Tags: java, jsf, gwt, icefaces

I'm a newcomer to JSF and am still trying to follow examples to learn the basics of how it works, and that has now lead me to begin exploring ICEFaces.

I love the concept behind GWT that you can just write in pure Java and have it compile down to JS and HTML, but I have also heard that ICEFaces offers a lot of things that GWT doesn't.

That led me to start thinking: is there a way to combine the two in a project, and get the best of both worlds? Is it possible to get the AJAX-centricity, rich UIs and underlying capabilities of JSF, but then use GWT to handle all the client-side code generation?

I looked at something called **ICEPush** which may very well do just this, but without fully understanding the roles both technologies play in MVC web apps I wanted to take a moment and see what the SO community thought of such a hybrid solution.

Having said that, I was wondering if someone could break down - in *quasi* laymans terms - the intentional difference between these two frameworks, and to give argumentation as to why they can be - or shouldn't be - combined inside the same project.

Essentially I'm looking for an AJAX-friendly, rich UI Java webapp framework that is open source, has an active dev community, and comes loaded decent/good documentation.

**Also, not that beggars can be choosers, but I'd appreciate it if answerers don't solicit other solutions besides ICEFaces or GWT. I'm very well aware that these are not the only two webapp frameworks out there, and this question isn't going to convince me to start using either of them; I'm simply interested if their strengths can be combined, or not.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF in general makes heavy usage of javascript. JSF or bette the JSF frameworks provide lots of components. The Javascript is generated on the fly.

GWT compiles the Javascript upfront. It provides some components as well. GWT is doing AJAX calls to its interfaces.

I'm not aware of any bridge that allows you to integrate JSF with GWT. So there is no interface and those technologies don't work together.

Both come with good documentation and have an active community.

Comment: Thanks Udo - [here](http://www.icepush.org/product/icepush-GWT.html) is the link to the bridge

Comment: To me it looks like the bridge is for icepush only and not for icefaces. Icepush allows you to initiate server side updates and to do partial page updates without sending full pages. I have doubts that the JSF internal model is compatible with gwt without some major integration work.

Answer (score 0):

ICEpush can be used directly with GWT; you can find out more about the integration here:

http://www.icepush.org/product/icepush-GWT.html

ICEpush provides a simple API to "push" notifications to the browser.  Essentially, users (or browser windows) are organized into groups.  When something interesting happens (such as a new photo uploaded to a photo sharing application) you can invoke a push on the group users.

In the case of the ICEpush GWT integration, you receive a callback into your "Java" code and can respond to the notification (such as, display the new photo).  A GWT application can potentially run offline, but that does introduce the risk of application code being subject to offline attack.

In the case of ICEfaces, the ICEpush integration is abstracted away: rather than a "push" to a group, you "render" a group.  With ICEfaces you request that all relevant pages be rendered on the server and any necessary page updates are sent to the browser.  This makes it particularly easy to add Ajax Push features to an ICEfaces application.

So, the choice is really whether you want to use JSF or GWT.  With JSF you have a standard server-side framework that emphasizes pages built from declarative markup.  It is the natural successor to JSP application development.  With GWT you have a procedural client/server distributed framework that emphasizes events and pages that are built from "Java" objects.  It is the natural successor to AWT/Swing on the web.  Both are very popular, so it's more a question of the technique you prefer.